# How to bind data from a database to a listbox using a disconnected database

Tags: c#, data-binding, dataset, database-connection

I have a listbox and would like to fill it with data from a database, the two must be linked so if i select a value from the listbox i can work with the entry in the database.

I'm using a disconnected database witch connects though a connection string:

```
conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnectionString)
```

I have read up on dataset's and think i need to create one and use it as my listbox data source, Then to have the data displayed looking neat i need to set the display name.

Could someone show me how to create a dataset that's connected to my table in my database and then show me how to bind it.

Database is called **TagCloudDB** and table is called **Tag** and just **listbox1**.

This is the code i have so far, but it just fills the listbox with System.Data.DataRowView.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                SqlDataAdapter daTags
                = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Tag", conn);

                DataSet dsTags = new DataSet("TagCloud");

                daTags.FillSchema(dsTags, SchemaType.Source, "Tag");
                daTags.Fill(dsTags, "Tag");

                daTags.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
                daTags.Fill(dsTags, "Tag");

                DataTable tblTag;
                tblTag = dsTags.Tables["Tag"];

                dplTags.DataSource = dsTags;
                dplTags.DataMember = "Tag";
                dplTags.DataBind();
            }
```

I did some thing similar in collage with VB and they have a **ValueMember** and **Displaymember**, Whats the equivalent in C#

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlConnection _connection = new Connection(connectionString)
SqlDataAdapter _adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_connection, "select * from tag")
DataTable _table = new DataTable()
_adapter.Fill(_table)

_connection.Close();

foreach(DataRow _row in _table.Rows)
{
 listbox.AddItem(new Item(_row["column1"], _row["column2"])
}
```

You don't need to mess with datatables. It automatically binds with the sql query.

Comment: You code looks to simple i don't think it will work. i'm not just trying to fill the listbox i need to bind it so i can work with selected Data